# BlackBerry - Set HTTP Proxy for connection

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me

I would like to set a `HttpProxy` for a subsequent `HttpConnection` on Blackberry.

In Android I would do something like:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, 
                   proxy);
```

What is the equivalent on Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't an API for this on BlackBerry.